# ¿cómo añado el path de php con XAMPP a visual studio code?

Tags: php, visual-studio, windows, xampp, rutas

Tengo instalada la última versión de XAMPP `(php7)` para windows 10, y no consigo añadir el path para poder trabajar mejor con `vs code`1.9
He intentado añadirlo pero no se guarda, y me devuelve esto:

```
C:\Windows\system32>path
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\El Xaxe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Comment: Apliqué la respuesta en Windows 7 ultimate y aparentemente todo funcionó OK.
De momento un enorme Gracias Marcos.

Comment: A mi me funcionó agregando al PATH la ruta c:/xampp/php, no creando una nueva entrada.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Agregar `php` la variable `PATH` en `Windows 8/10`

- En `Panel de control`, selecciona `Sistema`.
- Clic en el enlace `Configuración avanzada del sistema` (Menu izq.).
- Clic en la solapa `Opciones avanzadas`, click en el botón `Variables de entorno...`
- En la sección `Variables del sistema`, busca la variable de entorno `PATH` y selecciónala.
- Clic en Editar.
- Si la ruta al ejecutable `php.exe` no existe, has clic en `Nuevo` e ingresa el ruta completa (Ejemplo: `C:\xampp\php`).
- Cierra todas las ventanas haciendo clic en `Aceptar`.
- Vuelve a abrir la ventana `Símbolo del sistema (CMD)` y ejecuta `php -v`.

Si todo anduvo bien, `VSC` automáticamente detectara `PHP`.

### Configurar el path a `php.exe` en `VSC`

- Clic en `Archivo > Preferencias > Configuración de usuario`
- Agregar:

  ```
    {
      "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php"
    }
  ```
- en caso que no funcione "C:/xampp/php" colocar la ruta con el ejecutable

  ```
    {
      "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"
    }
  ```

Comment: No me va, lo he agregado tanto como usuario como de sistema, pero no funciona, ni apuntando  a `c:/xampp/php/php.exe` ni sin apuntar al ejecutable

Comment: No, no me han funcionado

Comment: ahh muchas gracias

Comment: al ejecutar path en el cmd me devuelve ``PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\RafaAdmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin``

Comment: ya está, era una cosilla que se me había colado

Comment: deberias incluir en tu solucion como hacerlo desde cmd y powershell, me gusta la cultura de ir utilizando más las terminales que los entornos graficos, más en windows que aveces abrir una ventana representa un riesgo.