# Añadir chromedriver.exe al PATH

Tags: python, chromedriver

Estoy tratando de incluir el chromedriver para ejecutarlo en mi codigo pero con
cualquiera de las opciones me sigue apareciendo el siguiente error.

```text
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿cómo añado el path de php con XAMPP a visual studio code?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47618/c%c3%b3mo-a%c3%b1ado-el-path-de-php-con-xampp-a-visual-studio-code) Lo único que cambia es que en vez del ejecutable de php, deberías añadir la carpeta donde está chromedriver.exe al PATH