# laragon no ejecuta laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laragon

Ejecuto el comando `php artisan serve` y en todos los proyectos me aparece error 404. Ya lo elimine y ahora estoy con san pero otro problema no me ejecuta el artisan:

```
php artisan serve
```

---

> ```
> php : El término 'php' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, 
> función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si      
> escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso,  
> En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
> + php artisan serve
> ```

Que puedo hacer para eliminar todo y volver a tenerlo funcionando

Comment: Hola michael, revisa la primer parte de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47644/16597)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que estás experimentando problemas al intentar ejecutar el servidor de desarrollo de Laravel usando el comando `php artisan serve`.

El primer error que mencionas indica que el comando `php` no es reconocido como un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Esto podría deberse a que el intérprete de `PHP` no está configurado correctamente en tu sistema o no está en la `variable de entorno` llamada `PATH`.

Esto suele suceder cuando copias el STACK (wampp, xampp, laragon, etc), en realidad esto aplica para todos los STACK (sean portables o no), es posible que el servidor pueda arrancar y funcionar pero a nivel de CLI, no lo hará adecuadamente por que no paso por la etapa de registro de una habitual instalación

Pasos para solucionar estos problemas y tener Laravel funcionando correctamente:

***Verificar la instalación de PHP:***
Asegúrate de tener PHP instalado en tu sistema y de que la ruta a la carpeta de instalación de PHP esté añadida a la `variable de entorno` llamada `PATH`. Puedes verificar la instalación y la versión de `PHP` ejecutando `php -v` en la línea de comandos.

Te dejo en imagen un ejemplo de esto (da la casualidad que soy usuario de Laragon, ***Observación:*** la variable que necesita de entorno es la que está en azul, ignora las otras que tengo, son para mi necesaria por los múltiples lenguajes de programación que suelo usar):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Añadir PHP al PATH:***
Si la ruta a la carpeta de instalación de PHP no está en tu variable de entorno PATH, debes añadirla manualmente. Esto permitirá que el sistema reconozca el comando php. La forma de hacerlo varía según el sistema operativo. Por ejemplo, en Windows, puedes editar las variables de entorno del sistema y añadir la ruta a la carpeta de PHP. ***(De esta forma lo solucionas)***

***Pasos a seguir:***

1. Determinar donde se encuentra el ejecutable de php:

```
    C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.28
```

2. añadirlo a la variable de entorno con CMD, PowerShell o el Entorno Grafico:

***Para Command Prompt (cmd):***

*Abre el Command Prompt.*

Ejecuta el siguiente comando, reemplazando  con la ruta completa a la carpeta de PHP (en mi caso, C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.28):

```
    setx PATH "%PATH%;<ruta-de-PHP>"
```

***Para PowerShell:***

*Abre PowerShell.*

Ejecuta el siguiente comando, reemplazando  con la ruta completa a la carpeta de PHP:

```
    $existingPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$existingPath;<ruta-de-PHP>", "User")
```

3. Reinicia tu equipo por si las moscas... no confió en Windows a veces aplica estos cambios al vuelo en caliente y en otras ocasiones no, requiriendo de un reinicio.

***Para Hacerlo con el Entorno Grafico de Windows:***

Sigue la respuesta que dio Marcos: [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47644/315134)

### Adicional:

***Verificar Laravel:***
Asegúrate de que estás ejecutando el comando php artisan serve desde la raíz del proyecto Laravel, donde se encuentra el archivo artisan. Si no estás en la carpeta correcta, el comando no funcionará.

***Composer:***
Laravel depende de Composer para administrar sus dependencias. Asegúrate de tener Composer instalado y actualizado. Puedes verificar la versión de Composer ejecutando `composer -V` en la línea de comandos.

***Instalar Dependencias:***
Si has clonado un proyecto Laravel desde un repositorio, asegúrate de ejecutar composer install en la carpeta del proyecto para instalar todas las dependencias necesarias.

***Reinstalar Laravel (si es necesario):***
Si sigues teniendo problemas, considera volver a crear el proyecto Laravel desde cero. Puedes hacerlo ejecutando `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel nombre-del-proyecto` en la línea de comandos. Luego, asegúrate de navegar a la carpeta del proyecto y ejecutar el comando php artisan serve.

Comment: yo lo tenia asi y de un momento a otro me slia el error 404, una pregunta amigo en si voy a seguir tus paso pero con xampp la carpeta de laragon bin donde va php en xampp donde coloco el php que tengo descargado

Comment: otra cosa mira que ahora voy a descargar composer y aparece esto composer global require laravel/installer
"php" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: PS C:\xampp\htdocs\Helloword> php artisan serve
php : El término 'php' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió 
correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ php artisan serve
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (php:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: todos los errores son lo mismo ... tienes que seguir los pasos y tienes que reiniciar el equipo y asegurarte de que todo este en su sitio... si abres el cmd y pones php -v te debe salir la version ejecutada de php ... y de hay en adelante todo debe funcionar ...