# Error en la terminal de Visual Studio Code: Php no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script...+

Tags: php, vscode

Ya instalé xampp, composer y laravel al pie de la letra con las indicaciones de un tutorial.

Una vez creado mi proyecto y todo lo de xampp ya esta en start llamo al servidor desde cmd y todo bien, o sea si puedo entrar y todo, pero, cuando ingreso por vscode y lo quiero llamar por la terminal me manda este error:

[image: Error con php]

Comment: Eso no es un error. Eso es que no tienes PHP instalado.

Comment: Si lo tengo! ya me fije por cmd con php -v. Igual ya lo arregle, no se que hice ni que moví pero de repente ya dió XD

Comment: Porque la terminal de XAMPP está separada de la terminal de Windows, lo que hace Code es crear una terminal de powershell (o bash para Linux y Mac), que es lo mismo como si tú la crearas por tu cuenta. Mientras que XAMPP tiene su propia terminal aislada de estas. Para añadir la instalación de PHP al sistema, deberás cambiar las variables de entorno.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [laragon no ejecuta laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/601254/laragon-no-ejecuta-laravel)

Comment: pregunta duplicada ... es lo mismo ...

Answer (score 0):

A mi me aparecía un error similar y lo que hice para resolverlo fue seguir lo siguiente:

- Propiedades del sistema>Variables de entorno
- En variables de entorno del sistema selecciona Path y da click en Editar>Nueva
- En Nueva te pedira escribir la ruta donde instalaste el php del xampp por ejemplo `C:\xampp\php`
- Una vez escrita le das click en <kbd>Aceptar</kbd>

> **Ojo:** Reinicia el VSC o cierra y abre la terminal, al ejecutar de nuevo debe de reconocer los comandos de php